# Jasmine - Unit Test: How to test onChange on an input

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have an input

```
<input matInput formControlName="nonSelectedSkillCtrl"  (keyup)="onChange($event)" />
```

I want to have a unit test that calls onChange function when I change the input value.
Here is my component.spec.ts:

```
it('Call onChange function', fakeAsync (() =>{
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
      let input = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input'));
      let el = input[0].nativeElement;

      expect(el.value).toBe('');
      el.value = 'f';
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
      fixture.detectChanges();
      
      expect(el.value).toBe('f');
    })
    tick();
    spyOn(component, 'onChange'); 
    expect(component.onChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }));
```

I have this error: Expected spy onChange to have been called once. It was called 0 times.
And even when I remove fixture.whenStable() I keep having the same error.

Comment: You are creating a unit test. In units tests, you do not write into inputs; you call functions and validate their results. If you need to validate an onchange event, you would need to call the function or change the input value and trigger the input keyup event.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to trigger the input keyup event.
If you have an exemple that would really help.

Comment: Use this as a guide https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: You're mixing up your async code logic, either only use `fixture.whenStable` or the `fakeAsync` with `tick`. Try setting  your expect for the spy to be called inside `fixture.whenStable`.

Comment: When I tried to call my except inside fixture.whenStable, the test passed but it told me that SPEC HAS NOT EXPECTATION.